# Preview the uploaded image in product page in Opencart

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, opencart2.x

I am using **Opencart Version 2.0.3.1**.

Customer can upload `image (upload file option)` in product page. I want to `preview the uploaded image` in the same page. The uploaded image is saved to `system/upload` folder and renamed with the filename + some string.

**How can I preview the uploaded image.**

The file upload button code is:(**catalog/view/theme/default/template/product.product.tpl**)

```
    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
    <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
      <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
      <button type="button" id="button-upload<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <?php echo $button_upload; ?></button>
      <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not optimal solution but you can try this one.

**Add**

`<img id="filePreview" style="display:none;">`

**After**

`<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>`

**Add**

```
var ref = '';

$(document).on('change','input[name="file"]',function(){
    ref = this;
});
```

**Before**

`$('button[id^=\'button-upload\']').on('click', function() {`

In ajax request of file upload, add this in success function

```
if (json['error']) {
        ref = '';
        $(node).parent().find('input').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'] + '</div>');
}

if (json['success']) {
    alert(json['success']);
    showImagePreview(ref);
    $(node).parent().find('input').attr('value', json['code']);
}
```

The show preview function is

```
function showImagePreview(input){

 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#filePreview').attr('src',e.target.result);
        $('#filePreview').show();
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
 }
}
```

Hope it will work :)